# I need to double-click the same button for the function to be activated, how do I solve it?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I created a function and added it to an HTML button element as an Onclick event, when I click just once it doesn't trigger, but when I click the second time it triggers the event, how do I make it trigger when I click for the first time? I'm using ReactJS

```
let filter = () => {

    if (
        document.querySelectorAll('.filter-button') &&
        document.querySelectorAll('.filter-item') &&
        document.querySelectorAll('.filter-element')
    ) {
        const filters = document.querySelectorAll('.filter-button')

        filters.forEach((filter) => {
            filter.addEventListener("click", () => {
                filters.forEach((filter) => {
                    filter.classList.remove("active");
                })
                filter.classList.add("active");
            })
        })


        const allFilterItems = document.querySelectorAll('.filter-item')
        const allFilterBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.filter-element')

        allFilterBtns.forEach((btn) => {
            btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
                showFilteredContent(btn);
            });
        });

        function showFilteredContent(btn) {
            allFilterItems.forEach((item) => {
                if (item.classList.contains(btn.id)) {
                    item.style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    item.style.display = "none";
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

```
        <Container fluid="true">
        { /* Banner */}
        <img src={BannerExample} width="1920" className="img-fluid mx-auto d-block banner-image" alt="Banner" />

        { /* Filtro de Produtos */}

        <div className="filter-scroller">
            <div id="destaque" className="filter-element-div">
                <button id="um" type="button" className="filter-element filter-button" onClick={() => { filter(); um(); }}><img alt="FilterItem" src={ShortsFiltro} width="100" className="img-fluid filter-element" /></button>
            </div>
            <div className="filter-element-div">
                <button id="dois" type="button" className="filter-element filter-button" onClick={() => { filter(); dois(); }}><img alt="FilterItem" src={ShortsFiltro} width="100" className="img-fluid filter-element" /></button>
            </div>
            <div className="filter-element-div">
                <button id="tres" type="button" className="filter-element filter-button" onClick={() => { filter(); tres(); }}><img alt="FilterItem" src={ShortsFiltro} width="100" className="img-fluid filter-element" /></button>
            </div>
            <div className="filter-element-div">
                <button id="quatro" type="button" className="filter-element filter-button" onClick={() => { filter(); quatro(); }}><img alt="FilterItem" src={ShortsFiltro} width="100" className="img-fluid filter-element" /></button>
            </div>
            <div className="filter-element-div">
                <button id="cinco" type="button" className="filter-element filter-button" onClick={() => { filter(); cinco(); }}><img alt="FilterItem" src={ShortsFiltro} width="100" className="img-fluid filter-element" /></button>
            </div>
            <div className="filter-element-div">
                <button id="seis" type="button" className="filter-element filter-button" onClick={() => { filter(); seis(); }}><img alt="FilterItem" src={ShortsFiltro} width="100" className="img-fluid filter-element" /></button>
            </div>
            <div className="filter-element-div">
                <button id="sete" type="button" className="filter-element filter-button" onClick={() => { filter(); sete(); }}><img alt="FilterItem" src={ShortsFiltro} width="100" className="img-fluid filter-element" /></button>
            </div>
        </div>

        { /* Produtos */}
        <Container fluid="lg Card-Container">
            { /* Categoria de Produto */}
            <h1 className="titulo-de-categoria">Produtos</h1>

            { /* Cards de Produtos */}
            <Row xs={2} md={4} className="g-4 filter-items">
                <Col className="filter-item um">
                    <a href="/produto">
                        <Card>
                            <Card.Img variant="top" src={ShortsJapones} />
                            <Card.Body className="d-grid gap-2">
                                <Card.Text className="value">
                                    R$50,00
                                </Card.Text>
                                <Card.Text>
                                    Shorts nike Preto, Branco e Vermelho
                                </Card.Text>
                            </Card.Body>
                        </Card>
                    </a>
                </Col>
                <Col className="filter-item dois">
                    <a href="/produto">
                        <Card>
                            <Card.Img variant="top" src={ShirtNike} />
                            <Card.Body className="d-grid gap-2">
                                <Card.Text className="value">
                                    R$70,00
                                </Card.Text>
                                <Card.Text>
                                    Shorts nike Preto, Branco e Vermelho
                                </Card.Text>
                            </Card.Body>
                        </Card>
                    </a>
                </Col>
                <Col className="filter-item tres">
                    <a href="/produto">
                        <Card>
                            <Card.Img variant="top" src={ShortsJapones} />
                            <Card.Body className="d-grid gap-2">
                                <Card.Text className="value">
                                    R$50,00
                                </Card.Text>
                                <Card.Text>
                                    Shorts nike Preto, Branco e Vermelho
                                </Card.Text>
                            </Card.Body>
                        </Card>
                    </a>
                </Col>
                <Col className="filter-item quatro">
                    <a href="/produto">
                        <Card>
                            <Card.Img variant="top" src={ShirtNike} />
                            <Card.Body className="d-grid gap-2">
                                <Card.Text className="value">
                                    R$70,00
                                </Card.Text>
                                <Card.Text>
                                    Shorts nike Preto, Branco e Vermelho
                                </Card.Text>
                            </Card.Body>
                        </Card>
                    </a>
                </Col>
                <Col className="filter-item cinco">
                    <a href="/produto">
                        <Card>
                            <Card.Img variant="top" src={ShortsJapones} />
                            <Card.Body className="d-grid gap-2">
                                <Card.Text className="value">
                                    R$50,00
                                </Card.Text>
                                <Card.Text>
                                    Shorts nike Preto, Branco e Vermelho
                                </Card.Text>
                            </Card.Body>
                        </Card>
                    </a>
                </Col>
                <Col className="filter-item seis">
                    <a href="/produto">
                        <Card>
                            <Card.Img variant="top" src={ShirtNike} />
                            <Card.Body className="d-grid gap-2">
                                <Card.Text className="value">
                                    R$70,00
                                </Card.Text>
                                <Card.Text>
                                    Shorts nike Preto, Branco e Vermelho
                                </Card.Text>
                            </Card.Body>
                        </Card>
                    </a>
                </Col>
                <Col className="filter-item sete">
                    <a href="/produto">
                        <Card>
                            <Card.Img variant="top" src={ShortsJapones} />
                            <Card.Body className="d-grid gap-2">
                                <Card.Text className="value">
                                    R$50,00
                                </Card.Text>
                                <Card.Text>
                                    Shorts nike Preto, Branco e Vermelho
                                </Card.Text>
                            </Card.Body>
                        </Card>
                    </a>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Container>

    </Container>
```

I tried checking the HTML elements through Javascript using If Else, I hoped I didn't need the second click to trigger the event

Comment: Can you post the html part?

Comment: This script goes completely against the React data-driven philosophy. You should not be directly manipulating elements. I suggest a review of the React intro tutorials to understand that better.

Comment: @javdromero yeah!

Comment: @isherwood could you explain me better?

Comment: You will not find event listeners attached in the script or classes being manipulated at https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html. You also should not rely on the presence of classes for your logic. Use _data_, not the DOM, to track application state.